# Custom UITableViewCell not accessing methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have a custom table view cell (Named MimoCell) which have a method that prepares the cell, like title, subtitle, image and stuff.

When I'm trying to access this method by passing the object it suppose to receive, I get a unrecognized selector sent to instance error. The complicated thing here is because I'm passing this object by reference, which I suspect is whats causing the error. 
 this is the cell

**MimoCell.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Mimo.h"
@interface MimoCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic)BOOL flagFriendCell;
@property (nonatomic)BOOL flagImageMimo;
@property (nonatomic,strong)UILabel *detailLabel;
@property (nonatomic,strong)UIButton *mimoImageBtn;
@property (nonatomic,strong)UIImage *mimoImage;


-(void)setMimo:(Mimo**)theMimo;

@end
```

**This is the MimoCell.m**

```
#import "MimoCell.h"
#import "currentUser.h"
@implementation MimoCell
{
    Mimo *mimo;
    currentUser *thisUser;
    NSTimer *syncCellTimer;
}
@synthesize detailLabel;
@synthesize flagFriendCell;
@synthesize flagImageMimo;
@synthesize mimoImageBtn;
@synthesize mimoImage;
-(void)setMimo:(Mimo *__autoreleasing *)theMimo{
    mimo = *theMimo;
    if(mimo.flagIsImage)
        flagImageMimo = NO;
    else
        flagImageMimo = YES;

    if([mimo.senderID isEqualToString:thisUser.userID])
        flagFriendCell = NO;
    else
        flagFriendCell = YES;


}



- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    thisUser = [currentUser instance];
    detailLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 87.0, 200.0, 12)];
    [detailLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helveltica" size:11]];
    [self.textLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    syncCellTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(syncCell) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [syncCellTimer fire];
    mimoImageBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
}
```

And this is where I handle it

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mimoCell";
    MimoCell *cell = (MimoCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){//It's never nil
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MimoCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    Mimo *workingMimo = [arrayOfMimos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setMimo:&workingMimo];//RIGHT HERE I GET THE UNRECOGNIZED SLECTOR ERROR



    return cell;
}
```

What am i doing wrong? I really want to pass by reference the MIMO object...

Comment: Try checking the actual type of the cell. Maybe you have entered the wrong classname in your nib file for your cell?

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at `[cell setMimo:..]` and check if you `cell` is indeed a type of class `MimoCell` ?

Comment: It's never nil??  I think you need to load the nib of your custom cell to init method in your CustomCell class .

Comment: Just checked the break point on [cell setMimo...] and the cell object is typed as MimoCell

Comment: Wierd thing is on the debugger the cell is set as MimoCell, but the error log is "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell setMimo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15da5ba0'"

Comment: That's wierd. And another wierd things is the way you are passing the object. Isn't object always passed by reference, since objects's name is reference itself.

Comment: It's not the way I'm passing the object, I created a test method, which only prints a NSLog, and it gave me the same error. So I'm probably initializing the cell wrong

Comment: Where are you making this cell (storyboard, xib, code)? It's not clear why your cell is never nil; have you registered the class or nib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. As we could see, the cell class on the cellForRowAtIndexPath: was indeed from my MimoCell class. But the error was generating a UITableCell class error. That showed me that somewhere, my cell was a simple UITableCell.

**IT WAS THE STORYBOARD.**

I Didn't set the class on the storyboard cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a custom nib to a cell use this in your `viewDidLoad` Method

```
 UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MimoCell" bundle:nil];
 [tableViewName registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MimoCell"];
```

I think this is what you were missing.